# Renew interest in a (someone else's) very, very old question

Tags: discussion, bump

I have basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2834548/405017). There is no good answer there now.

It was asked over 5 years ago. While I am not directly asking for a library recommendation, it is my hope that progress in Ruby or 3rd party libraries in the past five years has improved the situation.

Things I could do:

1. Ask a new question and hope that it does not get closed as a duplicate, attempting to explain that it's a "new" question because the surrounding situation has (I think) changed so much.
2. Provide a hefty bounty and hope that it actually gathers interest.
3. Post a meta question about it that has no value to anyone and was asked many times before in the hope SO users will look at it.
4. ...?

Is there a fourth option? What says the community on how to proceed?

Comment: It's clear that other options should be in addition to option #2, and so I've pursued that avenue for now, but leave this question open in case additional community-approved options are available.

Comment: Are you **sure** it's not a library recommendation?  This question *very much* reads like a library recommendation.  I'm not sure that bountying it was the best action.

Comment: And now we can't close it for looking for an off-site resource, because of the bounty :(

Comment: Goodness! Why the down votes?! Regardless of whether it was right to add the bounty (I guess it wasn't), is this question I'll formed in some way?

Comment: The downvotes here are only indicating disagreement with the actions previously taken on the question.  This particular question probably shouldn't have been closed, since you are sort of seeking some input from the community.

Comment: Here's why I believe this is not asking for a library: I'm asking how to achieve a goal. Perhaps that goal requires a library, perhaps not. In either case, it requires code (using the library or not). If I asked how to use a thread, that's a valid question, right? If I ask how to write a PNG, that might require a library, but would still be valid, yes?

Comment: Not really. "I want to do X" is essentially the same as a library request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer this in two parts:  the first being what you would want to do *in general*, and the second being what you should have done *this time*.

In general, if you want to renew interest in someone else's older question, the best option to utilize is the bounty system.  Placing a bounty has a chance to get some more attention on the question.  Outside of that, you could advertise a link to it.

For *this* case, you have to understand why the community reacted the way it did:  **this is nothing more than asking for a library to solve the issue.**

I don't disagree that you would *want* a library to solve this particular issue, and if they were using a *specific* library, then this would've been acceptable.  But, they're looking for a general library to tackle this.

Here's what it'd look like if we got rid of most of the noise.

> I need to do X from a Ruby console program.
>
> After much searching, I've come across these libraries:
>
> - [list of libraries here]
>
> These seem to help me, but I need something to do a little more. I
>   also must be able to do specific functions (so a particular type of
>   library is out).

You'd get nothing but library recommendations, which is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow.